# Exclude pattern in RegExp match Golang

Tags: regex, go, looker-studio, re2

I need to extract a part of a string in Golang for a dashboard in Google Data Studio. This is the string:

```
ABC - What I need::Other Information I do not need
```

To get the part between the hyphen and the first colon I have tried `([\\-].*[\\:])`, which includes both, the hyphen and the colons.

That might be an easy question for more experienced RegExp users, but how do I match only the words in between?

Comment: https://regex101.com/

Comment: I know this page and tried my best there. But I do not find the right anchors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this:

```
-(.*?):
```

Here the first capture group is your desired result.
 [Example](https://regex101.com/r/wzEUei/2)

Sample Source: ( [run here](https://ideone.com/pDQ3gh) )

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    var re = regexp.MustCompile(`(?m)-(.*?):`)
    var str = `ABC - What I need::Other Information I do not need`
    rs:=re.FindStringSubmatch(str)
    fmt.Println(rs[1])

}
```